# Why does running Apps Script function from Apps Script API returns 500?

Tags: google-apps-script, http-status-code-500, google-apps-script-api

*Keep in mind the difference between Apps Script(AS for short) projects (code.gs) and the Apps Script API.*

The general idea is to be able to create AS projects, write functions inside and execute them, all from a 'parent' AS project.

After confirming that there was no AS-specific method for creating new AS projects (other than by hand), I recently managed to get the AS API working from within an AS project.

The [projects.create](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/create?hl=fr) method works great for creating new projects.

The [projects.updateContent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/updateContent?hl=fr) method works great for writing code inside newly created projects.

However, I'm having trouble using the [script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/scripts/run?hl=fr) method to try and execute functions contained in new projects from the API

Here is how I tried to get it working:

```
function runScript() {

    var scriptId = 'target_script_id'
    var functionName = 'target_function_name';

    var accessToken = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

    var url = 'https://script.googleapis.com/v1/scripts/' + scriptId + ':run';

    var payload = {
        'function': functionName,
        'devMode': false
    };
  
    var options = {
        'method': 'post',
        'contentType': 'application/json',
        'payload': JSON.stringify(payload),
        'muteHttpExceptions': true,
        'headers': {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
         }
    };
  
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    var responseData = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    Logger.log (responseData);
    return responseData; 
}
```

and here is the error I received:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Internal error encountered.",
    "status": "INTERNAL"
  }
}
```

Comment: Typically [500 error code](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/troubleshoot-api-errors#500-internal-server-error) is an internal server error. It is best to file it in [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191635&template=824102) for further investigation.

Comment: @Serenity yeah, Internal Server Error, but very consistent one. I've tried several times, a few days apart, on several different projects. There might as well be something wrong with my method or syntax causing 500 error, which is why I'm asking the question here. But you're right, I did open an Issue Tracker ticket.

Comment: 1. Are you able to manually run the `target_function_name`? 2. Does both the calling project and the called script have the same GCP?

Comment: @Serenity The ``500`` is the ``200``-result from AS-api and therefore `500` is from the AS itself(that OP created). The link you posted is for sheets api and more importantly, the tracker link is for Admin SDK. The correct link for AS-API is [`327918+`](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:327918%2B) Avoid posting direct links, if you aren't sure that is the correct link for the issue. You may simply point out the issue tracker without linking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further investigating in the AS-API documentation, it turns out that the target script first needs to be deployed as API-executable.
Then I set the deployment id as target in the script.run request, and the targeted function is executed.

However, it only postponed my problem, because now I can't deploy the target script from the API using the [deployments.create method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.deployments/create?hl=fr), I get a 500 error again.